# Are farm raised fish unhealthier than their wild caught counterparts?

Tags: nutrition, fish

I like to eat fish on a regular basis, most notably salmon and tuna. Recently, I've been reading about some of the dangers of fish raised on fish farms. Notably, these can include

- Increased level of PCB's
- High levels of antibiotics to combat crowded conditions
- Toxic environment (Often in excrement being flushed out to sea)
- Lower level of Omega-3 fatty acids
- Added dyes and colors to enhance flesh color

Has any of this been proven, or is this just media hype?

Comment: Some ideas http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquaculture_of_salmonids#Issues

Answer (score 6):

- The claim that farmed salmon have more PCBs than wild salmon is
  **true**.

  For example, this paper from [Science](http://www.sciencemag.org/cgi/pmidlookup?view=long&pmid=14716013) shows that the PCB (and other organic pollutant) concentrations are approximately 8 times higher in farmed than in wild salmon.

[image]

- The claim that Omega-3 fatty acids are lower in farmed than wild
  salmon is **false**.

According to the USDA, [farmed salmon](http://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/4687?format=Full&reportfmt=pdf&pdfQvs=%7B%7D) has a higher concentration of Omega-3 fatty acids than [wild salmon](http://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/4531?format=Full&reportfmt=pdf&pdfQvs=%7B%7D) at 4.2g vs 3.4g for the default 1/2 fillet tested.

- The claim that dyes are added to make salmon pink is **true**.

[This paper](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0019032) describes an assay to measure astaxanthin content, which is one of the dyes added to the feed of farmed salmon.

> Astaxanthin is the single most expensive constituent in salmonid fish feed. Even though astaxanthin constitutes less than 20% of the total fish feed costs, control and optimization of the concentration of astaxanthin from feed to fish is of paramount importance for a cost effective salmonid fish production.